# How to configure Aurelia to load modules from a folder?

Tags: naming-conventions, aurelia

Aurelia has this fantastic [ViewLocator](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/templating/latest/class/ViewLocator) strategy. I can't figure out how to make it do the same for modules. Here's a sample `/src` setup:

```
- src/
    - main.js
    - app/
        - app.js
        - app.html
    - foo/
        - foo.js
        - foo.html
    - bar/baz/
        - baz.js
        - baz.html
```

Following this convention, I'd like to be able to load `app` with the name `app` rather than `app/app`, `foo` with `foo` rather than `foo/foo`, and `baz` with `bar/baz` rather than `bar/baz/baz`.

So in effect, `<path>/<module>/<module>` should be accessible from `<path>/<module>`

In Aurelia, what is the best way to set this convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a convention for this, and it's actually a general convention for node packages. First, structure your app module using an `index.js` entry point.

```
- src/
    - main.js
    - app/
        - index.js
        - app.js
        - app.html
```

Next, in your `main.js` code, use the feature "app". This tells Aurelia to look for `app/index.js` and load it as a plugin.

**main.js**

```
export configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .feature('app');
}
```

You can read more information about features here: [Aurelia Features](http://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/app-configuration-and-startup#organizing-your-app-with-features)